# How to fix "System.Reflection.TargetException" error in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

why when I get back to the page an error pops up System.Reflection.TargetException: „A target object is required for the non-static method.”

```cs
public ActionResult HistoryOrder(int id)
{
    var orderList = db.OrdersItems.SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderItemsId == id);

    orderList.IsHistory = true;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ListYourProduct");
}
```

```cs
public ActionResult ListYourProduct(string userId)
{
    var user = UserManager.FindById(userId);

    var orderItems = db.OrdersItems.Where(x => x.UserName == user.UserName && x.IsHistory == false).ToList();

    return View(orderItems);
}
```

```xml
<a href="@Url.Action("HistoryOrder", "Order", new { id = item.OrderItemsId, userId = User.Identity.GetUserId()})">Archiwizuj</a>
```

Comment: Does the error indicate which line of code is causing this?

Comment: Yes: var orderItems = db.OrdersItems.Where(x => x.UserName == user.UserName && x.IsHistory == false).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the userId = User.Identity.GetUserId() from route in link and get it in the controller by

```cs
public ActionResult ListYourProduct()
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var user = UserManager.FindById(userId);

    var orderItems = db.OrdersItems.Where(x => x.UserName == user.UserName && x.IsHistory == false).ToList();

    return View(orderItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
        public ActionResult HistoryOrder(int id)
    {
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var orderList = db.OrdersItems.SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderItemsId == id);

        orderList.IsHistory = true;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("ListYourProduct",userId);
    }

<a href="@Url.Action("HistoryOrder", "Order", new { id = item.OrderItemsId})">Archiwizuj</a>
```

Comment: yes. you don't need pass userId to rout becuse The current user id on the site is always available in the HttpContext.User or User